# motorcycle 07suzuki boulevard

Tags: motorcycle

So i just bought this bike and was told it needed a cdi cause it wasnt firing ok well they also had caught the bike on fire and burnt the wiring harness up . so i downloaded a wiring diagram an wired it accordingly.  But no fire thing is i got voltage going to coil and with my inline spark testing wire i see it light up only once as so
on as i hit the botton. Witch is it the rectifier or igniter?

Comment: I will make this comment: I had to help a colleague sort out his wiring as it was damaged. He had put the wires back together as looked ok. Trouble was, was that he had not recognised the different shades of the primary colours in use - so, when you looked quickly there were green wires - when you looked in detail, those wires had tracer colours red, white etc but were also different shades of green - about 4 base shades. So, are you sure you got all of them correct?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!